# Can't use the "Install New Software" to add cdt on eclipse using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm new to linux and we are required to use linux ubuntu for computer science class.
I need to install Java, C and c++ on eclipse. I got this worked on windows 8 it was pretty easy install. I tried adding cdt using install new software i kept getting this message.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: C/C++ Development Tools SDK 8.4.0.201406111759 (org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group 8.4.0.201406111759)
>
> Missing requirement: C/C++ Development Tools UI 5.8.0.201406111759 (org.eclipse.cdt.ui 5.8.0.201406111759) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency: From: C/C++ Development Tools 8.4.0.201406111759 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 8.4.0.201406111759) To: org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group [8.4.0.201406111759]
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency: From: C/C++ Development Platform 8.4.0.201406111759 (org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group 8.4.0.201406111759) To: org.eclipse.cdt.ui [5.8.0.201406111759]
>
> Cannot satisfy dependency: From: C/C++ Development Tools SDK 8.4.0.201406111759 (org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group 8.4.0.201406111759) To: org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group [8.4.0.201406111759]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your Eclipse has the CDT installed.
2. If it is installed, Make sure that it is the latest version! else upgrade it!
3. Then it should install properly!